# PMQ integration with IBM Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am exploring IBM Bluemix platform and checking whether it support IBM PMQ as a Predictive Analytics service in Bluemix.
Or it is not added to Bluemix suite.

Answer (score 0):

The Bluemix platform includes an IBM Predictive Analytics service. For details, you can log into [bluemix.net](https://console.ng.bluemix.net) and search the [Catalog](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/). You can ask follow-up questions about IBM products or offerings at [IBM developerWorks Answers](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smart-spaces/12/bluemix.html). Stack Overflow is for technical programming questions.